# Html.DropDownList selected value change

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

i have 2 html.dropdown list where one bind to xml file and show part
and other dropdown show cites of this part .

now how when change part (change value of first dropdownlist)
in other dropdownlist show cites of this part?

Answer (score 4):

Populate dropdowns using [this](http://lacyg.info/asp-net-mvc-3-dropdownlist-binding-with-xml.software-developer) tutorial. Make User Controls (partial pages) for dropdowns. Call second partial using ajax on change event of the first dropdown

Comment: short and sweet. i like it. +1